# How do I set the flags/switches for the aspnet_compiler in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, build, csc

I'm having some trouble with namespacing for a web application project - front-end files are being compiled into separate assemblies under the `ASPX.directory1_director2_directoryn_filename` namespace format and I want everything in one dll.

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/899130/bc30560-default-aspx-is-ambiguous-in-the-namespace-asp) and setting the `-o` flag would appear to be exactly the solution I'm looking for. However I build my code in VS2010 using the standard `Build` menu option and I can't find anywhere I can set it. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you meant aspnet_compiler. Here is a [tutorial](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jamesche/archive/2007/09/27/automating-aspnet-compiler-in-visual-web-developer.aspx). It's related to Visual Web Developer 2008. But the basic idea is the same - use the External Tools dialog to create you desired action.

Comment: Thanks for the link - I *did* mean the aspnet_compiler :-o

I took a look at the available options in the MS documentation - would I be right in thinking its the `-fixednames` option that is doing this and that it is set by default in Visual Studio?

Comment: I don't know exactly. Create a little project in VS and compile with aspnet_compiler it will take not more that 5 minutes. Also this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2702111/aspnet-compiler-fixednames-does-not-work can be useful for you

Comment: That works pretty well, thanks! It seems to pick up errors in the front-end (markup files) that the regular build process misses. eg.  example badly formed tags.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a Web Site Project, the ASP.NET compiler options can be used from the Publish dialog.  For a Web Application Project, you can use [Web Deployment Projects](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=24509) to enable pre-compilation (technically, WDP should work for WebSites as well).